# Calculate Duration between two dates using python

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

I have dataset

```
          DaySchedule                  DayAppointment 
          2016-04-29 18:38:08           2016-04-29
          2016-04-29 16:08:27           2016-04-29
          2016-04-26 15:04:17           2016-04-29
```

I want to calculate the duration time between the Schedule date and the appointment date if they on the same day then the duration will be 0 otherwise  I will subtract Appointment day from Schedule day.

```
     def duration_time(x,y):
         x= x.dt.date
         y= y.dt.date
        if x==y:
               return 0
       else:
           return x-y

     Patient["duration"] = Patient.apply(lambda Patient:duration_time(Patient["DayAppointment"], Patient["DaySchedule"]), axis=1)
```

**After I run this cod I had this Error :
AttributeError: ("'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'", u'occurred at index 0')**

any idea why I got this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `numpy where` + `dt.date` + `sub` instead:

```
Patient.DaySchedule=pd.to_datetime(Patient.DaySchedule)
Patient.DayAppointment=pd.to_datetime(Patient.DayAppointment)

Patient['duration']=np.where(Patient.DaySchedule.dt.date==Patient.DayAppointment.dt.date, 0, Patient.DaySchedule.sub(Patient.DayAppointment))

    DaySchedule DayAppointment      Duration
    2016-04-29 18:38:08 2016-04-29  0 days 00:00:00
    2016-04-29 16:08:27 2016-04-29  0 days 00:00:00
    2016-04-26 15:04:17 2016-04-29  -3 days +15:04:17
```

You can also just get the days:

```
Patient['Duration']=Patient.DaySchedule.sub(Patient.DayAppointment).astype('timedelta64[D]')

DaySchedule DayAppointment      Duration
2016-04-29 18:38:08 2016-04-29  0.0
2016-04-29 16:08:27 2016-04-29  0.0
2016-04-26 15:04:17 2016-04-29  -3.0
```

Using sub, it takes:

```
1.59 ms ± 63.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Just using simple subtraction takes nearly a ms more:

```
Patient['Duration']=np.where(Patient.DaySchedule.dt.date==Patient.DayAppointment.dt.date, 0, Patient.DaySchedule-Patient.DayAppointment)

2.51 ms ± 172 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```